# Pandas shift rows with non-fixed period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having the following datastructure

```
+------+------+-------+----------------------+--------------------+
| uuid | type | score | next_score_incorrect | next_score_correct |
+------+------+-------+----------------------+--------------------+
|    0 | A    |   100 | 110                  | 120                |
|    0 | A    |   110 | 120                  | 120                |
|    0 | B    |   120 | na                   | na                 |
|    1 | B    |    80 | 90                   | 100                 |
|    1 | A    |    90 | 100                  | 100                |
|    1 | B    |   100 | na                   | na                 |
+------+------+-------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

Per record i'm trying to calculate the next biggest score within the same uuid, but only from the type B records (example column next_score_correct).
So far I've only been able to calculate the next biggest score, ignoring type by doing the following (column next_score_incorrect):

```
df.sort_values(by='score', ascending=True, inplace=True)
df.groupby('uuid')['score'].shift(periods=-1)
```

How would I adjust my code to take into consideration that I want to shift to the next B type score, which is not necesarrily the next?

Comment: why does row 4 equals 90 ?

Comment: It shouldn't, that was a typo @YOLO.